# Fn::ImportValue does not match type {Array}

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I faced an issue with using the export and import functionality in CloudFormation. When I tried to import a value which actually is a list (array) I received the following error message "does not match type {Array}".

vpc.yaml (snippet)

```
PrivateSubnets:
  Description: A list of the private subnets
  Value: !Join [",", [!Ref PrivateSubnetOne, !Ref PrivateSubnetTwo]]
  Export:
    Name: !Join ["-", [!Ref "Environment", "PrivateSubnets"] ]
```

pipeline.yaml (snippet)

```
Subnets:
  Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${Environment}-PrivateSubnets"
```

Error message:

```
    Property validation failure: [Value of property {/VpcConfig/Subnets} does not match type {Array}
```

Answer (score 7):

This code resolved the issue;

```
Subnets: !Split 
   - ","
   - Fn::ImportValue: 
       !Sub "${Environment}-PrivateSubnets"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split + Select should work as you'll be able to split the array and select each item individually, e.g.:

```
!Select [2, !Split [",", !ImportValue AccountSubnetIDs]]
```

...which selects the 2nd element from the imported array of subnet Ids.