# How to retrieve an array using importValue() from an existing Cloudformation stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to import a list of subnets from an existing CloudFormation stack into a stack that I'm deploying.  The values are stored as a comma-separated string in the Outputs of the existing stack, e.g.

```
subnet-1, subnet-2, subnet-3
```

The import code I'm attempting to use is:

```
const privateSubnets = Fn.importValue(PrivateSubnets).split(',');
```

I was hoping I could just use .split(','), but I get an error when I try to use the privateSubnets variable later on in a VPC declaration:

```
const myVpc = Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'Vpc', {
      vpcId: vpcId,
      availabilityZones: [0, 1, 2].map(i => Fn.select(i, Fn.getAzs())),
      privateSubnetIds: privateSubnets,
      publicSubnetIds: publicSubnets
    });
```

I have searched around but it doesn't look like I can do this.  As you can see above I'm importing the availability zones and then parsing them out, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this that works with an importValue() function.

Comment: Since `vpcId` and `availabilityZones` are the only required fields, perhaps you can leave off the subnets.  Since you already have the vpc id, could that be enough?

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a Fargate deployment, and it requires the public and private subnet fields to be populated.

Comment: Don't export them as one string with commas export them all separately with subnet1 subnet2 etc

Comment: @AnonymousAlias it seems like that would make life difficult if there is an unknown number of subnets to import.  Can you even do an importValues() if you only know a prefix of the keys you're looking for?

Comment: Does this question help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601220/fnimportvalue-does-not-match-type-array

Answer (score 0):

`Fn.importValue` returns a [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) - so in order to use the values from within the ref you're going to need to use the [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html).

```js
const privateSubnets = Fn.split(',', Fn.importValue(PrivateSubnets));


const myVpc = Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'Vpc', {
    vpcId: vpcId,
    availabilityZones: [0, 1, 2].map(i => Fn.select(i, Fn.getAzs())),
    privateSubnetIds: [Fn.select(0, privateSubnets), Fn.select(1, privateSubnets), Fn.select(2, privateSubnets)],
    publicSubnetIds: publicSubnets
});
```

Unfortunately, there is not a good way to know the length of the Ref and iterate over it to properly map privateSubnetsId to the ImportValue.

It *might* be a cleaner long-term option for you to use an SSM Parameter rather than a CloudFormation Export to store/pass the value of the private subnet IDs. As you are able to load the string value of an SSM Parameter into your CDK Stack and use that.